# How can I find all syscalls that have to be whitelisted for seccomp?

Tags: linux, system-calls, seccomp

I have an existing program that I would like to sandbox using seccomp (v2).

How can I find what seccomp rules I need to allow for the program?

---

I've tried adding `seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(…), 0)` for all syscalls printed by `strace -xfc a.out`, but apparently that wasn't enough, since I'm still getting "SIGSYS, Bad system call" when I run the program with seccomp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most reliable way is to switch your seccomp filter to return `SECCOMP_RET_TRAP` ("send catchable `SIGSYS` on error") rather than `SECCOMP_RET_KILL` ("kill the process with an uncatchable `SIGSYS`"), then print the `siginfo_t` from the signal handler, then commit suicide.

Comment: Is that equivalent to `scmp_filter_ctx ctx = seccomp_init(SCMP_ACT_TRAP);`?

Comment: Yes, that's one of the C-level libraries; I was answering at the syscall level since that's the same.